# Mouse left button click renders an application "Not Responding"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mouse

I develop W32 applications using VS 2019 on a laptop running Windows 10.

I have written a utility function that writes a series of text strings to the main window of the calling app while said function plays a wav file.  The objective is to coordinate the incremental display of the various text strings, which represent song lyrics, to the corresponding musical phrases in the wav file.  When the tune completes, the app closes.

Albeit crude, the function performs as expected when the Debug or Release version of the host app is executed within the VS2019 IDE.

Likewise, when execution of the host app is invoked from Windows Explorer or a desktop icon, the app functions as expected provided that User does not click the left mouse button while the function is executing.   However,

1. If the left mouse button is clicked while the mouse pointer is over the desktop or another window, the tune continues to play, but the app stops writing the subsequent lyric strings.  After the tune completes, the app closes as expected.
2. If the button is clicked while the mouse is over the app window, the app behaves in the same way with the addition of “(Not Responding)” appearing in the window title bar.
3. The wav file feature is a recent enhancement to the function.  I do not believe that this anomaly is related to said feature, as the anomaly also manifested identically before the wav file enhancement was incorporated.

Following is the relevant segment of code from the utility function.

Does anyone have insight as to the cause of this anomaly and how to remedy same?  I have tried such options as

1. Disabling the host app HWND.
2. Executing the function within a child window.
3. Setting focus to desktop within the function.

No luck.

Thank you for attending to this.

UPDATE:  The sample code previously supplied has been replaced by the following single code module which when built as a Win32 app demonstrates the anomaly.  BTW, the edit feature for this site would not let me cut the old code -- hence, my earlier comment about not being able to edit.   However, it did allow me to paste over the original code snippet.

```
enter code here
 //---------------------------------------------------------------
 // TEST_Goodbye.cpp : App to demonstrate anomaly in function     
 // LongGoodbye.                                                  
 //---------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                  
 #include "framework.h"                                           
 #include <math.h>                                                
 #include "TEST_Goodbye.h"                                        
                                                                  
 #define MAX_LOADSTRING 100                                       
 #define IDC_PUSHBUTTON        160                                
                                                                  
 // Global Variables:                                             
 HINSTANCE hInst;  // current instance                            
 WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];        // The title bar text      
 WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];  // the main window class na
                                                                  
 // Forward declarations of functions included in this code module
 ATOM  MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);                      
 BOOL  InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);                              
 LRESULT CALLBACK  WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);           
 INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);           
                                                                  
 //=====================================================          
 // Function LongGoodbye.                                         
 //=====================================================          
 void LongGoodbye(                                                
    HDC hdc                                                       
    )                                                             
 {                                                                
   HWND hWnd = WindowFromDC(hdc);                                 
   RECT Rect;                                                     
   int k;                                                         
   int kk = 8;                                                    
   int color[3] = { 32,128,32 } ;   // Rich forest green.         
   int Delay[] = { 700, 1400, 1400, 1400, 1400, 1400, 1400, 1400, 
      1400, 1400, 1400, 1400, 4200 };                             
   COLORREF BackGroundColor = RGB(color[0],color[1],color[2]);    
                                                                  
   const char *szFarewellMessage[12] = {    // vs2019             
     "Farewell."                                                  
   , "Adieu."                                                     
   , "A German phrase, goodbye-high."                             
   , " "                                                          
   , "How sad"                                                    
   , "you will"                                                   
   , "not give this App a try-high!"                              
   , " "                                                          
   , "Goodbye."                                                   
   , " "                                                          
   , "Good-byyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyye."                                 
   , " "                                                          
   };                                                             
                                                                  
   //-------------------------------------------------------------
   //                                                             
   //-------------------------------------------------------------
   //X PlaySound(L"SoLongFarewell_v06", hInst                     
   //X   , SND_RESOURCE | SND_ASYNC);                             
   GetClientRect(hWnd, &Rect);                                    
   Rect.top = kk;                                                 
   Rect.bottom = Rect.top + 2 * kk;                               
   for (k=0; k<12; k++)                                           
   {                                                              
     SetFocus(hWnd);                                              
     Sleep(int(floor(0.875*Delay[k])));                           
     SetBkMode (hdc,TRANSPARENT);                                 
     DrawTextA(                                                   
         hdc                                                      
       , (char*)szFarewellMessage[k]                              
       , -1                                                       
       , &Rect                                                    
       , DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_NOCLIP                       
       );                                                         
     Rect.top    += kk;  // Half line-height spacing after empty t
                         // line.                                 
     Rect.bottom += kk;                                           
     if (strlen(szFarewellMessage[k]) >1)                         
     {                                                            
       Rect.top  += kk;  // Full line-height spacing after non-emp
                         // text line.                            
       Rect.bottom += kk;                                         
     }                                                            
   }                                                              
   Sleep(int(floor(0.875*Delay[12])));                            
   SendMessage (hWnd, WM_DESTROY, 0, 0L) ;                        
 }                                                                
                                                                  
                                                                  
 int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,                  
   _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,                              
   _In_ LPWSTR  lpCmdLine,                                        
   _In_ int  nCmdShow                                             
   )                                                              
 {                                                                
   UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);                         
   UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);                             
                                                                  
   // Initialize global strings                                   
   LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
   LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_TESTGOODBYE, szWindowClass,         
       MAX_LOADSTRING);                                           
   MyRegisterClass(hInstance);                                    
                                                                  
   // Perform application initialization:                         
   if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))                       
     return FALSE;                                                
                                                                  
   HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance,               
     MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TESTGOODBYE));                           
                                                                  
   MSG msg;                                                       
                                                                  
   // Main message loop:                                          
   while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))                        
   {                                                              
     if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))      
     {                                                            
       TranslateMessage(&msg);                                    
       DispatchMessage(&msg);                                     
     }                                                            
   }                                                              
   return (int) msg.wParam;                                       
 }                                                                
                                                                  
                                                                  
 //---------------------------------------------------------------
 //  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()                                  
 //---------------------------------------------------------------
 ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)                        
 {                                                                
   WNDCLASSEXW wcex;                                              
   wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);                              
   wcex.style  = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;                         
   wcex.lpfnWndProc  = WndProc;                                   
   wcex.cbClsExtra  = 0;                                          
   wcex.cbWndExtra  = 0;                                          
   wcex.hInstance  = hInstance;                                   
   wcex.hIcon  = LoadIcon(hInstance,                              
     MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_TESTGOODBYE));                           
   wcex.hCursor  = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);                
   wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);                
   wcex.lpszMenuName  = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_TESTGOODBYE);        
   wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;                           
   wcex.hIconSm  = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance,                       
      MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));                                
   return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);                                
 }                                                                
                                                                  
 //---------------------------------------------------------------
 //  FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)                       
 //---------------------------------------------------------------
 BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)             
 {                                                                
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global varia
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle,              
         WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,                                     
        20, 20, 300, 300, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);  
   if (!hWnd)                                                     
     return FALSE;                                                
   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);                                    
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);                                            
   return TRUE;                                                   
 }                                                                
                                                                  
 //---------------------------------------------------------------
 //  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)                
 //---------------------------------------------------------------
 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam  
     , LPARAM lParam)                                             
 {                                                                
   static HWND hPB = NULL;                                        
   static HDC  hdc = NULL;                                        
   switch (message)                                               
   {                                                              
     //****message************************************************
     case WM_CREATE:                                              
     {                                                            
       //---------------------------------------------------------
       // Create Goodbye Button.                                  
       //---------------------------------------------------------
       RECT Rect;                                                 
       GetClientRect(hWnd,&Rect);                                 
       hPB = CreateWindow(                                        
           L"button"                                              
         , L"Goodbye"                                             
         , WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON                  
         , 6                                                      
         , Rect.bottom-36                                         
         , 180                                                    
         , 30                                                     
         , hWnd                                                   
         , (HMENU)IDC_PUSHBUTTON                                  
         , hInst                                                  
         , NULL                                                   
         );                                                       
       ShowWindow(hPB,SW_SHOW);                                   
     }                                                            
       return 0;  // END case WM_CREATE:                          
                                                                  
     case WM_COMMAND:                                             
     {                                                            
       switch (LOWORD(wParam))                                    
       {                                                          
         case IDM_ABOUT:                                          
           DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd,  
             About);                                              
           break;                                                 
                                                                  
         case IDM_EXIT:                                           
           DestroyWindow(hWnd);                                   
           break;                                                 
                                                                  
         case IDC_PUSHBUTTON:                                     
           hdc = GetDC(hWnd);                                     
           LongGoodbye(hdc);                                      
           ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);                                   
           break;                                                 
                                                                  
         default:                                                 
           return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);   
       }                                                          
     }                                                            
     break;                                                       
                                                                  
     case WM_PAINT:                                               
     {                                                            
       PAINTSTRUCT ps;                                            
       hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);                               
       // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...        
       EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);                                       
     }                                                            
     break;                                                       
                                                                  
     case WM_DESTROY:                                             
       PostQuitMessage(0);                                        
       break;                                                     
                                                                  
     default:                                                     
       return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);       
   }                                                              
   return 0;                                                      
 }                                                                
                                                                  
                                                                  
// Message handler for about box.                                 
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam     
   , LPARAM lParam)                                               
{                                                                 
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);                                 
  switch (message)                                                
  {                                                               
    case WM_INITDIALOG:                                           
      return (INT_PTR)TRUE;                                       
                                                                  
   case WM_COMMAND:                                               
     if ((LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK) || (LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL))
     {                                                            
       EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));                           
       return (INT_PTR)TRUE;                                      
     }                                                            
     break;                                                       
  }                                                               
  return (INT_PTR)FALSE;                                          
}
```

Comment: Nothing in what you posted is related to the left mouse button. Please supply a [mre]

Comment: I am baffled by your assertion that the problem is unrelated to my left mouse button.  Please explain.  
Also, I have prepared and verified a single code module which demonstrates the strictly repeatable, 100 % "if and only if" correlation of the left mouse button click and the anomaly described. How do I post it?   This venue will not allow me to edit my original post, nor does not provide adequate space to post it as part of this comment.

Comment: I never said your problem was unrelated to the left mouse button. I said you didn't post any code related to the left mouse button and asked you to post a [mre]. Still waiting.

Comment: And, how do I post my "minimum producible example"?  Please advise.

Comment: See the Edit button?

Comment: Please take a look at my edit to my original post.

Comment: Missing framework.h and TEST_Goodbye.h

Comment: To create the application, simply    

1. Use VS 2019 IDE to create a new Win32 project called TEST_Goodbye.    
2. Revise the autogenerated TEST_Goodbye.cpp file as previously indicated.    
    No other autogenerated files -- among which are TEST_Goodbye.h   
    and framework.h -- require modification.   
3. If you wish to reinstate the commented-out line of code   
    that plays a tune, simply revise the autogenerated *.rc file    
    to define the object L“SoLongFarewell_v06” to any *.wav file    
    of your choice.     
4. Build the Release version of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I moved most of the guts of function LongGoodbye(HDC) to a modeless dialog function called LongGoodbyeGUI(..).  I then revised LongGoodbye(HDC) to create this modeless dialog.
Problem solved.